# Use Star (*) with mysql inner join?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, inner-join, wildcard

I have always done inner joins that look like this

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Where you specify each row you want.  I am currently working with a table that has 50 rows however and I don't want to type all these SQL joins with all the rows, is there a way to say "select * from Orders, then give me Customers.CustomerName join on ...." instead of specifying every row from the first table?

Comment: i think you mean a 50 columns table? the catch when using * is lazy programming style but it comes with a cost in terms off performance because more data needs to be sended to the client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT Orders.*, Customers.CustomerName
```

You simply define what you want via `tablename.column` so you can either specify an existing column name, or use star `*` to indicate all columns from that table.

Answer (score 1):

In applications it's highly recommended to be explicit about columns you want to select and to avoid `*`, but if you are running these queries for yourself it makes sense to use it:

```
SELECT table_name.*
```

Note that you can also omit the qualifying table name from the column if the column name is unique.  That is `Customers.CustomerName` can just be `CustomerName` unless `Orders` *also* has a `CustomerName` column.  In the same vein, `Orders.OrderID` can just be `OrderID`.